# "Invalid partition table!" BIOS message, but all works?

Tags: boot, partitioning

I just moved a primary drive from one laptop to another (different manufacturer, higher specifications). When booting, the BIOS complains "Invalid Partition Table!" However, I then just press a key and it continues normally.

While it's not the end of the world to have to kick this to get it to boot, it's a little disturbing, and I'd prefer to have everything right.

Without damaging the existing data, how might I go about fixing this?

Comment: Probably not optimal for installation into a different laptop. Fixing the partition table would require wiping the drive, laying down a new partition table, and reinstalling the OS. You might try `fsck` on the drive, and see what it reports. And a `sudo fdisk -l` to see if the partitions are aligned.

Comment: Not sure if I was clear. The drive was "fine before I moved it" (and it's SSD, so it's less likely physical damage.) And as I say it works perfectly except for this message??

Comment: There's no apparent physical damage, but one of optimization. Personally, if you're planning on keeping the drive in its new laptop, I'd wipe it, lay down a new (GPT on larger drives, or newer UEFI computers) partition table, and reinstall the software.